# Find connecting nodes shared between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Cypher beginner question. I know how to get all the friends of someone called Rebecca, and the edges between them:

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person)-[r*1..10]->(friends:Friend)
RETURN rebecca, friends,
       extract(x IN r | {rel: x, start: startNode(x), end: endNode(x)})
```

And I know how to get all the friends of someone called Robert, and the edges between them:

```
MATCH (robert:Person)-[r*1..10]->(friends:Friend)
RETURN robert, friends,
       extract(x IN r | {rel: x, start: startNode(x), end: endNode(x)})
```

But how do I get all the friends that Robert and Rebecca have in common with each other? Either by combining these two queries, or if there's a simpler way altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person)-[:FRIEND]->(friends:Friend)<-[:FRIEND]-(robert:Person) 
where rebecca.name = "Rebecca" and robert.name= "Robert"    
RETURN friends
```